# C Drive is full, but 90% is unsccessible space?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, backup, windows-server-2016

My server's C drive have a 1 TB SSD drive, but 98% of the disk is used.

If I use WinTree or WinDir, it says I'm using 90 GB on my C drive. 
But Windows says I'm using 940 GB.

I tried a tool called "SpaceSniffer" and I could see that inaccessible space is using 820 GB.

1. Have any of you tried this before?
2. The server has a lot of drives. I'm using Windows Backup to take a backup from D to F. No backups are stored on C. I don't backup C. Could Windows backup have some hidden files on the C drive?

What I tried so far:

- chkdsk
- Treesize (Admin and non-admin)
- windirstat (Admin and non-admin)
- vssadmin list shadowstorage as Administrator

Note: Every drive on my server is encrypted and has been for months.

Comment: Use Tree Size Administrator and set to see Hidden Files, Folders.  You may have set Windows to make backups on a weekly basis or something like that.

Comment: “could see that unsccessible space is using 820GB (or something like that).” - Please provide a screenshot.